# Limitations while using @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

I am using a custom font using `@font-face`.
Everything is working but some specific Turkish characters are not displaying properly.

Check out [this page](http://rajesharma.com/hotali) and enter the Turkish page 
You will notice some Turkish characters are not displaying properly.
The same character is showing properly when I use it in Photoshop with that font.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

[here http://rajesharma.com/hotali/imgs/shot.jpg](http://rajesharma.com/hotali/imgs/shot.jpg)

You see the S character in iletisim
That S is different in shape than the S in ANA SAYFA
The shape of both the S should have been same.
They are same when I use that font in Photoshop.
Just the browsers are not getting them correct

Comment: Not speaking Turkish, it all looks fine to me :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@font-face` font file you're using doesn't have the glyphs necessary to display those accented characters, so the browser used another font's glyphs in its place as a fallback.

Fixing this will depend on how you have obtained the `@font-face` file, but it is likely that the generator or font hosting service you're using is stripping out the extended Latin characters to reduce file size. If this is the case, you can try looking at the options provided by the service to include these characters in the `@font-face` file.

Comment: Yes that did it. I was using the optimal conversion at font-squirrel. I used the expert settings and generated it for turkish language. Thanks !! :)